# What is maximum value of "m" for following equation?

Tags: combinatorics

**QUESTION:**

What is maximum value of "m" for following equation?
$$\Sigma\ (^{10}C_i)( ^{20}C_{m-i})$$

where i is from 0 to m.

(A) 5

(B) 10

(C) 15

(D) 20

**MY ATTEMPT:**

I have written equation as,

$$\Sigma\ (^{30}C_m)$$

Now we know, in $\Sigma\ (^{n}C_r)$ when n is even  r = n/2  gives maximum value.

So 30/2 is 15, which is correct given answer.

But I don't know whether my is logic is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Chu-Vandermonde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) identity (equation $7$), where 
$$\sum_{i=0}^k{p \choose i}{n-p \choose m-i}={n \choose m}$$
so we have
$$\sum_{i=0}^k{10 \choose i}{20 \choose m-i}={30 \choose m}$$
and, as you have mentioned, the value of $m$ that will maximise the result will be $15$.

Comment: Okay, It means I have done it in correct way. Thanks :)

Comment: Your answer is correct, but there should be no summation sign, so you should have $(^{30}C_m)$ instead of $\Sigma\ (^{30}C_m)$.

Comment: Okay, got it. thanks once again